# "The import cannot be resolved" after adding a dependency with maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, classpath, apache-storm

I am new to maven and haven't touched java in years, so my apologies if this is incredibly obvious.

I'm building a project with a dependency on [apache storm](https://github.com/apache/incubator-storm), and my project is unable to view the libraries and resolve the dependency to include it with `import backtype.storm.topology.BasicOutputCollector`, for example.  Eclipse draws a nice red line under the word `backtype` and tells me that `the import cannot be resolved.`

After generating the structure of my project, I filled in my `pom.xml` file and ran `mvn package` to grab all of the dependencies (which succeeded) and `mvn eclipse:eclipse` to build the eclipse project structure.

My pom.xml looks like this:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>   <groupId>com.myproj.storm</groupId>   <artifactId>storm-experiments</artifactId>   <packaging>jar</packaging>   <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>   <name>storm-experiments</name>   <url>http://github.com/myaccount/storm-experiments</url>

    <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>github-releases</id>
      <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/github-releases/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>clojars.org</id>
      <url>http://clojars.org/repo</url>
    </repository>   </repositories>
     <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>storm</groupId>
      <artifactId>storm</artifactId>
      <version>0.9.0.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>   </dependencies> </project>
```

To save space, the generated `.classpath` is [here](http://pastebin.com/NrJGS7Cj).  Here is the top and the entry for the storm jar:

```
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/test/java" output="target/test-classes" including="**/*.java"/>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/java" including="**/*.java"/>
  <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/storm/storm/0.9.0.1/storm-0.9.0.1.jar"/>
```

My question is simple.  Why can't I include these dependencies in my project without getting the "the import cannot be resolved" problem.  There's clearly a step I'm missing, probably related to my classpath, but I can't figure out what that is.

Thank you

Comment: As a note, you should prefer using m2eclipse to manually generating Eclipse `.project` files. Much less likelihood of problems like this, which appears to be an issue of not mapping the `M2_REPO` item to the local repository.

Comment: Probably obvious, but is your project Maven-configured in Eclipse? You should see a small "M" on your project icon. Moreover, expand it, and you should see the Storm dependency under Maven dependencies, if everything went right.

Comment: @watery I don't think it is Maven-configured in Eclipse.  I used mvn eclipse:eclipse to generate the project, but there were no other maven/eclipse steps in putting together my project.  I'm assuming by the comments of chrylis and you, I completely missed a step on setup.

Comment: @chrylis I didn't manually create the .project files, they were generated from the mvn eclipse:eclipse call after I manually filled in the pom.xml file.  Is there a step to automate that instead?

Comment: I never used the Eclipse plugin, but reading [its documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/eclipse-mojo.html) it looks like it should generate all of the Eclipse project & configuration files. I have no idea why it's not working, but to create a new Maven project I'm used to create an empty project in Eclipse (or check it out from a VCS) and then convert it to Maven with (right click on the project) -> Configure -> Convert to Maven project. If there's no POM, a dialog pops up asking some informations, otherwise the existing POM is read. You may give that a try.

Comment: I'm saying that you shouldn't be using `mvn eclipse:eclipse` anymore. Instead, use Import>Maven project in Eclipse, and m2e will handle the generation (and everything else necessary).